# Deleted items from local storage persist after refresh (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, filter, local-storage, splice

I have an expense tracker where I add an expense to a table and it saves to localStorage & displays those items onto the UI. When I delete an item however, it is not being removed from localStorage like it should be. It deletes from the UI, then comes back upon refresh.

I used a Brad Traversy tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaMCxVWtW58&t=811s) for help on structure as I am trying to understand Object Oriented Programming better. I've seen other people online with the exact same structure, just different names. But so far, no answers.

The code is split up into 3 different classes, LineItem, UI, and Store which is used for localStorage. Here is the remove method in my Store class:

```
static removeLineItem(id) {
  let lineItems = Store.getLineItems();
  lineItems.forEach((lineItem, index) => {
    if(lineItem.id === id) {
      lineItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });

  localStorage.setItem('lineItems', JSON.stringify(lineItems));

}
```

And here is where it's called:

```
document.querySelector('.table').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  
  // Remove lineItem from Store
  Store.removeLineItem(e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText)
  
});
```

This is the markup for each row to show where the id is coming from when I traverse the DOM:

```
const lineItemRow = document.createElement("tr");
    lineItemRow.classList.add("table-success", "line-item");
    lineItemRow.innerHTML = `
      <th>${lineItem.name}</th>
      <td>$${lineItem.amount}</td>
      <td>${lineItem.date}</td>
      <td>${lineItem.id}</td>
      <td class="btn-container">
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger cursor-pointer delete">X</span>
      </td>
    `
```

I tried using filter() instead of splice() but it did not work.

```
const filteredLineItems = lineItems.filter(lineItem => lineItem.id !== id);
```

I have read that splice() is not the best method to use as it can screw things up, but besides filter, I am unaware of any other method to do this. I have also used filter() in React Apps before many times and it works perfectly. So I can't understand why it least filter does not work.

There are no error messages either. And I have logged the id in the remove method and in the eventListener and they both show up fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And let me know if you need to see another piece of the code or markup.

EDIT: Store.getLineItems()

```
static getLineItems() {
  let lineItems;
  if(localStorage.getItem('lineItems') === null) {
    lineItems = [];
  } else {
    lineItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lineItems'));
  }
    return lineItems;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Store.getLineItems()` implementation, please?

Comment: Sure, just did.

Comment: Hm, looks fine to me. Did you check with the devtools where in your code it goes wrong, and what string the local storage actually contains?

Comment: I've been looking  in both the console and the Application tab. There are no errors, so that's what's really confusing to me. And in the Application tab, when I click my remove button, nothing gets removed from local storage.In previous times when I've used local storage, when there are no more items in the array, there is just an empty array in storage. So I know the issue is it's not being removed. I just don't understand why.

Comment: Bergi, I just figured this out, see my post below. Thanks for your help!! When you asked what string the local storage actually contains, I didn't really understand what you meant. But that prompted me to look at the data in storage and realized the id was being stored as a string, not a number.

Comment: Yes, `.innerText` is a string :-)

Answer (score 1):

Oh my gosh. I just figured this out. The id that I set is a number. (I used Math.random())
In this method, I use === which compares the type, not just the value. In local Storage, the id is stored as a string, not a number. SO of course it won't work. The code is just doing what I am telling it to do :)

So I needed to use == instead.

```
static removeLineItem(id) {
  let lineItems = Store.getLineItems();
  lineItems.forEach((lineItem, index) => {
  if(lineItem.id === id) {
     lineItems.splice(index, 1);
   }
});
```

localStorage.setItem('lineItems', JSON.stringify(lineItems));

}